# ¿porque mi app borra los datos de mi Tabs - fragment cuando me desplazo entre ellos?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragment

Tengo una app que estoy desarrollando para un trabajo de mi instituto donde debo medir diferentes tiempos de forma dinámica en distintos niveles, y he logrado hacer que se muestren los diferentes cronómetros en los 5 tabs-fragments que requiero, pero cunado paso del primer tab-fragment que tiene un cronometro ya iniciado, al tercer o cuarto tab-fragment para iniciar un cronometro y vuelvo a la primera pantalla donde estaba corriendo mi cronometro este se ha reiniciado y me muestra el cronometro en cero. no entiendo como o porque hace este reset y como puedo evitarlo. agradecería cualquier tipo de ayuda o consejo.

Este es mi main.java:

```
public class index extends AppCompatActivity {

private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPagerAdapter mViewAdapter;
private ViewPager viewer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_index);
    mViewAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewer= findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    loadPager(viewer);
    tabLayout=findViewById(R.id.Tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewer);

}

private void loadPager(ViewPager viewPager){
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new 
ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new Fragment_Nivel_1(), "Nivel 1");
    adapter.addFragment(new Fragment_Nivel_2(), "Nivel 2");
    adapter.addFragment(new Fragment_Nivel_3(), "Nivel 3");
    adapter.addFragment(new Fragment_Nivel_4(), "Nivel 4");
    adapter.addFragment(new Fragment_Nivel_5(), "Nivel 5");
    adapter.addFragment(new guardar(), "guardar");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

  }
}
```

... mi ViewPager Adapter:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private final List<Fragment>fragmentList= new ArrayList<>();
private final List<String> fragmentTitle= new ArrayList<>();

public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title){
    fragmentList.add(fragment);
    fragmentTitle.add(title);
}

public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return fragmentTitle.get(position);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return fragmentList.get(position);
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return fragmentList.size();
 }
}
```

Y mi Activity_Main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".index">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:title="Cronometro">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/Tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tabItem"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Nivel 1" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tabItem2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Nivel 2" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tabItem3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Nivel 3" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tabItem4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Nivel 4" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tabItem5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Nivel 5" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Código de uno de  los fragment con el list-adapter que muestra los N cronometros:

```
public class Fragment_Nivel_1 extends Fragment {
private View view;
private ListView listView;
private TextView lblId;
private TextView txtId;
private TextView lblTarea;
private TextView txtTarea;
private TextView lblInicio;
private TextView txtInicio;
private TextView lblFin;
private TextView txtFin;
private int contentView;

public void setContentView(int contentView) {
    this.contentView = contentView;
}

class registros{
    int id;
    String nombreTarea;
    String nivelTarea;
    String tiendaTarea;
}
private ArrayList<String> cont = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<registros>contenido = new ArrayList<registros>();
Helper_ListaTareas helperTarea;
Helper_ListaPrcesos helperCrono;

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_nivel1);
    helperTarea = new Helper_ListaTareas(getContext());
    helperCrono = new Helper_ListaPrcesos(getContext());
    crearLista();

}
private void crearLista() {
    Cursor cursor = helperTarea.mostrarTareaNivel1();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        cont.add(cursor.getString(0));
        registros reg = new registros();
        reg.id = cursor.getInt(0);
        reg.nombreTarea = cursor.getString(1);
        reg.nivelTarea = cursor.getString(2);
        reg.tiendaTarea = cursor.getString(3);
        contenido.add(reg);
    }
}


private class listAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private int layout;

    public listAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull 
List<String> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);

        layout = resource;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull 
ViewGroup parent) {
        viewHolder main = null;

        if (convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);
            final viewHolder vista = new viewHolder();
            convertView.setTag(vista);

            vista.lblid = convertView.findViewById(R.id.labelId);
            vista.txtid = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtId);
            for (int i=0;i<contenido.size();i++){
                String idP = String.valueOf(contenido.get(i).id);
                vista.txtid.setText(idP);
                System.out.println("id:"+idP);
            }
            vista.lblpro = convertView.findViewById(R.id.labelName);
            vista.txtpro = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
            for (int i=0;i<contenido.size();i++){
                String nameP = contenido.get(i).nombreTarea;
                vista.txtpro.setText(nameP);
                System.out.println("tarea"+nameP);
            }
            vista.crono = convertView.findViewById(R.id.chrCronometro);
            vista.btninicio = convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
            vista.btninicio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if (!vista.runnig){
                        vista.crono.start();
                        vista.crono.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - 
                        vista.pauseOffSet);
                        vista.runnig=true;
                        if (vista.runnig){
                            vista.btninicio.setText("Pausa");
                        if(vista.txthinicio.getText().toString().equals("")) 
                        {
                                vista.hrs = new Date();
                                vista.hora =new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss 
                                a");
                                vista.horas = vista.hora.format(vista.hrs);

                       vista.txthinicio.append(String.valueOf(vista.horas));
                            }else{
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    }else{
                        if (vista.runnig){
                            vista.crono.stop();
                            vista.pauseOffSet =SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() 
                                               - vista.crono.getBase();
                            vista.runnig = false;
                            if (!vista.runnig){
                                vista.btninicio.setText("Finalizado");
                                vista.btninicio.setEnabled(false);
                                vista.hrs = new Date();
                                vista.hora =new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss 
                                a");
                                vista.horas = vista.hora.format(vista.hrs);
                                //view.txthfin.setText("");

                          vista.txthfin.append(String.valueOf(vista.horas));
                            }

                            String id = vista.txtid.getText().toString();
                            String name = vista.txtpro.getText().toString();
                            String time = vista.crono.getText().toString();
                            String inicio = 
                            vista.txthinicio.getText().toString();
                            String fin = vista.txthfin.getText().toString();
                            System.out.println(id);
                            System.out.println(name);
                            System.out.println(time);
                            System.out.println(inicio);
                            System.out.println(fin);
                            if (id.length()!=0 && name.length()!=0 && 
                            time.length()!=0 && inicio.length()!=0 && 
                            fin.length()!=0){
                                GuardarDatosTarea(id,name,time,inicio,fin);
                            }else {
                                return;

                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            });
            vista.lblinicio = convertView.findViewById(R.id.labelInicio);
            vista.txthinicio = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtInicio);
            vista.lblfin = convertView.findViewById(R.id.labelFin);
            vista.txthfin = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtFin);
        }else {
            main = (viewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            main.txtid.setText(getItem(position));
        }

        return convertView;

    }
}

private void GuardarDatosTarea(String id, String name, String time, String 
inicio, String fin) {

    boolean insertData = helperCrono.insertCronometro(id, name, time, 
inicio, fin);

    if (insertData) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Almacenado Correctamente", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        System.out.println("datos almacenados");
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Algo va mal " + helperCrono.Error, 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        System.out.println("datos no almacenados");
    }

}

public class viewHolder{
    TextView lblid;
    TextView txtid;
    TextView lblpro;
    TextView txtpro;
    Chronometer crono;
    Button btninicio;
    TextView lblinicio;
    TextView txthinicio;
    TextView lblfin;
    TextView txthfin;
    private boolean runnig;
    private long pauseOffSet;
    private SimpleDateFormat hora;
    private Date hrs;
    private String horas;
}


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable 
ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_nivel1, container, false);
    listView = view.findViewById(R.id.ListNivelUno);
    listView.setAdapter(new listAdapter(getContext(), 
R.layout.layout_lista_tarea, cont));



    return view;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hola, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so], te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Comment: Un ViewPager adapter mantiene vivos los fragments que están en la posición seleccionada y los adyacentes, los demás los destruye. Si quieres tener un cronómetro en cada fragment y que funcionen tal com tu quieres deberías crear 5 cronómetros dentro de tu Activity index. Los fragments solo deberían consultar el cronómetro que les corresponde i mostrar su valor. Una opción más avanzada seria poner los 5 cronómetros dentro de un Service para poder hacer que incluso sobrevivan al cierre de la app.

Comment: @Jofre gracias por responder y creo entender bien lo que me dices, pero quizás omití info importante y es que mis fragments son listas vacías que lleno con un List adapter que me trae el cronometro desde un xml con todos los objetos necesarios y los repite N veces en base a una tabla de datos cargada en sqlite, de momento son 20 cronómetros que muestro repartidos en 5 tabs-fragments distintos. mi pregunta entonces va ahora a si es mejor hacer los 20 cronómetros fijos en el index.xml y de ahi llamarlos como tu indicas o puedo hacer que funcione lo que me dices con mis listas como están ahora?